# Starting point for converting jersey project to standard servlet app

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jersey

I am trying to implement the example shown [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Google-App-Engine-Java).

The example seems to be for a jersey setup, which I am not using or familiar.  How hard would it be to convert this to a standard java servlet project(idk how to name this)

What steps should I take.  It seems most of the @ annotations need to be changed to servlets.

This also seems very differnt from the standard appengine upload setup which all takes place in one servlet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be a lot of work to rework the code to standard servlet and remove jersey. Jersey takes away so much boilerplate code. For example the JSON conversion is done by jersey, which otherwise would have to be custom implemented.

And you can for sure deploy more than one servlet to gae, in which way should this be standard?

Just look at the first method:

```
  @GET
  @Path("/url")
  public Response getCallbackUrl() {
    String url = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/rest/file");
    return Response.ok(new FileUrl(url)).build();
  }
```

When using only standard servlet you would need to do:

1. Servlet Definition and Mapping in web.xml to /url
2. Implement a HttpServlet, override doGet() method
3. Send Response Code 200 OK
4. Set appropriate HTTP Response Headers
5. Convert Response to JSON and write it to response

Comment: How hard would it be to add jersey to my project? I can't seem to find it.  jersey.java.net is not available.  is there somewhere else I can find it?

Comment: I was talking about the single servlet the app engine example uses for upload

Comment: if you are using maven, it is not hard, as it is added in the pom.xml. otherwise you have to get the JAR files, and put them into the lib folder, which is also not hard.

Comment: This is great, almost got it all working, any idea where I find @XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)        They don't seem to be included with jersey.core

Comment: you find it in the jaxb-api jar, and i think you need jaxb-impl too - you can find this by jarfinder for eg (google)

Comment: How do I force json output, it seems the first method is sending xml not json.

Comment: It is the content negotioation, normally you need to set the "Accept" HTTP Request header to "application/javascript" and then you get JSON, or add @Produces("application/json") to the service method